# How to find only sunday from date column using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to find out only Sunday present date column from range 1 NOV to 31 Dec 2021 using bigquery

Kindly suggest syntax for bigquery

Comment: Can you provide an example desired out put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function like the one below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 11-01-2021 AND 12-31-2021 AND EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM date) = 1
```

Also, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) you can learn more about how to create date functions into BigQuery.